# some of my website page links are still live even jQuery modal dialog pops up

Tags: jquery, css

how do I make all my links frozen from on my site when a jQuery dialog popups?.I have done the z-index thing but nothing seems to work. I have everything pretty much layed out clearly on a screenshot. here is the link. http://wsoplugins.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/pluginproblem.png

thank you so much. -Ron.

here is the code...

```
$j(function{
       $j('#mystuff').dialog({modal: true, resizable: false, width: 800, height: 250});
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing your code (and a screenshot really doesn't count in this case), all I can suggest is:

```
$('a').click(
    function(){
        var modal = $(selectorToFindModalDialogue);
        if (modal.is(':visible')){
            return false;
        }
    });
```

[JS Fiddle proof-of-concept](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/nsEgK/1/).

References:

- [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).
- [`is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/).